# how to change mouseover colors of emacs' org-links?

Tags: org-mode, faces, org-link

`M-x customize-face RET org-link RET`

I understand that I can access and change the appearance of links when there's no mouse over them, but I can't find a way to change the background color and font color when I put my mouse over them. The current color combination has a really low contrast.

- emacs 28.1
- org-mode 9.5.2

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `M-x describe-face RET TAB` and look for a face which looks like the one you want to change. Alternatively, place the cursor on a link, press `C-u M-x what-cursor-position RET` (or `C-u C-x =` by default) and look for the name of the face for the mouse-face text property. You'll find that this face is called `highlight`.

Then you can change this face in the usual ways, for example using `M-x customize-face RET highlight RET`.